# User-Defined Type Not Defined error in function to multiply two matrices

Tags: vba, function, excel, matrix

I want to create a function which receives two arguments to make some matrix operations. What I want to do is the following:

```
li(3,5)
```

Then:

```
[1 , 3 , 5 ] * [1
                3
                5]
```

So the result would be `35`. As you see, I add the value of 1 to the matrix, then multiply by its transpose.

My code is the following but I receive the message `"User-Defined Type Not Defined error"`

```
Public Function li(a As float, b As float) As Variant
Dim mat(1 To 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
Dim re As Variant


mat(1, 1) = 1
mat(1, 2) = a
mat(1, 3) = b

re = WorksheetFunction.MMult(mat, WorksheetFunction.Transpose(mat))

li = re




End Function
```

I use Excel 2007.

So, What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in type `float` in VBA. For single precision floating point numbers use `Single`, for double precision floating point numbers use `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

I think to some extent your code is 'reinventing' standard functions (and no harm in that), with `1` in A1, `3` in B1 and `5` in C1:

```
{=MMULT(A1:C1,TRANSPOSE(A1:C1))}
```

returns `35`.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason I don want 1 and the arguments of the function to be in cells of excel.

Comment: Thanks!, that sounds better, I really don`t know well how to work with matrices in Excel.